# Converting Date Time index in Pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a date time index list which has elements looking like 2015-01-15.
Can I convert them to Jan 01, 2015 & still keep them as datetime object? What's the procedure here?

Comment: Not possible in python/pandas.

Comment: because there is default format of dates/datetimes, if need different formats then output is strings (datetimes are lost, get string repr of datetime)